# Trouble evaluating residue of a function

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals, residue-calculus, complex-integration

I am asked to evaluate

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ixz}}{(1+iz)^2}$, where x is just a constant

Since $e^{izx}$ decays in the upper halfplane, the integral is equal to

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ixz}}{(1+iz)^2} = 2\pi i \mathrm{Res}f(z)$.

But when calculating the poles i run into som trouble.

$f(z)$ obviously has a pole of second order at z = i, but using the following formula to calcualte the residue:

$\lim_{z \rightarrow i} \frac{d}{dz}((z-i)^2 \frac{e^{ixz}}{(1+iz)^2})$

i run into some problems, as the denumerator still gives a singularity for $z=i$ after differntiation.

Any tips as to how i should proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't. Note that$$\frac{z-i}{1+iz}=-i$$and that therefore$$(z-i)^2\frac{e^{ixz}}{(1+iz)^2}=(-i)^2e^{ixz}=-e^{ixz}.$$

Comment: Thanks, but I dont see how $\frac{z-i}{1+iz} = -i$

Comment: Because$$\frac{z-i}{1+iz}=-\frac{-z+i}{1+iz}=-\frac{i^2z+i}{1+iz}=-i.$$

Comment: Thank you very much!